# Reading a perl data structure into ruby

Tags: ruby, perl

I have a file containing a few thousand lines of perl, defining some large and complex data structures.

For reasons I won't bore you with, I need to read and process this data in ruby.

Is there

- a really easy way of reading this data directly into ruby? (hey, I can dream :-)
- some ruby module that will help me?
- a different strategy that I should use (exporting from perl in some format, and importing into ruby perhaps)?

I'm very familiar with perl but am a ruby novice.

Comment: `use JSON; print encode_json $complex_data`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd advise you to go for a representation that is common to both languages like JSON.